# API for manipulating raw, unsigned transactions

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc, transaction-data, rpc, stagenet, library

I'm trying to create something which involves messing with (unsigned) transaction data, using the Rust library [monero-rs](https://github.com/monero-rs/monero-rs). All I need to do is import an unsigned transaction, access the contents, then export the *modified* unsigned transaction.

However, this library does not appear to have any support for importing unsigned transactions, which does make sense given that it does not have signing capabilities.

Is there any way to do this? Preferably I'd like to stay in Rust. Importing a signed transaction, modifying it, then exporting the new one would also be acceptable, but I can't find a way to make any wallet "re-sign" an already signed transaction. Any other ideas? Or if it's necessary to implement this from scratch, is there any documentation available on how unsigned transactions are encoded?

Before you say this is a stupid idea and not the intended way of creating transactions, I know, and I will be doing all experiments on stagenet. And yes, I'm also aware that manipulating transaction data will often result in corrupting the outputs and making funds inaccessible.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an unsigned transaction using the official wallet RPC. It's fully documented under [sign_transfer](https://www.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#sign_transfer).

The 3rd party library you reference appears to have the necessary functions to create / load an unsigned transaction (see the [blockdata](https://github.com/monero-rs/monero-rs/blob/main/tests/blockdata.rs) tests for examples of loading), but not to actually sign or transfer.

Comment: Yes, I know how to create unsigned transactions, but there does not appear to be a way to import them into the library. The examples you linked appear to only support signed transactions.

Comment: "The examples you linked appear..." < Have you actually *tried* though? I just tried an unsigned tx (using `deserialize::<Transaction>("hex")`), and it worked fine.

Comment: Yes, I tried and it spat out an error. Just to be clear, what RPC method are you using?

Comment: `transfer` with `"do_not_relay":true,"get_tx_hex":true,"get_tx_metadata":true` then loading the blob into the `deserialize` above. But as answered, the library doesn't support signing or transferring, so limited in use for you.

Comment: tx_blob has CLSAG signatures attached: https://i.imgur.com/4FrOnq7.png . When using a view-only wallet, "unsigned_txset" is given, but that cannot be read by the library.

Comment: I [get](https://paste.debian.net/hidden/d460c2de/) `Clsags: []`. You sure you created your tx with a watch-only wallet like the linked docs mention? ("on a read only wallet"). Regardless, as answered, you cannot sign or transfer using that 3rd-party library.

Comment: It appears that you are running outdated software. The `MGs` field, containing `MgSig`s, is for the MLSAG signatures which were replaced with CLSAGs in 2020. That transaction also uses Bulletproofs instead of Bulletproofs+,

Also, as I said, I don't necessarily need to sign transactions from within this library. Only import, edit, and export unsigned transactions. Signing can be done elsewhere.

Comment: Weird. I run 18.2.2 (latest). But just tried another one and it is different. I think I may have updated the monero-rs library.